# Return a single MySQL results with multiple values from a row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple search query in php with:

```
SELECT * FROM `books` NATURAL JOIN `authors` WHERE `books`.`title` LIKE '%$search%
```

In the returned result I expect the same book title to have more then one author. I would like to display the title just once with multiple authors, and can't seem to find an elegant solution to print the wanted values without doing at least 2 loops with multiple counters like so:

```
    $last = ""; $i = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetchRow(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
    $current = $row['title'];
    if ($current != $last) {
        $i += 1;
        $books[$i]['title'] = $current;
        $books[$i]['author'][] = $row['author'];
        $books[$i]['pages'] = $row['pages'];
    } else {
        $books[$i]['author'][] = $row['author'];
    }
    $last = $current;
}

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $return_result .= 'Title:  '  . $book['title']  . '<br />';
    foreach ($book['author'] as $author) {
        $return_result .= 'Author: '  . $author . '<br />';
    }
    $return_result .= 'Pages:  '  . $book['pages']  . '<br />';  
    $return_result .= '<br />';
}
```

Please tell me if there's a better way to do this, maybe in MySQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function will give a delimited list of authors.

```
SELECT b.title, b.pages, GROUP_CONCAT(a.author)
    FROM books b
        NATURAL JOIN authors a
    WHERE b.title like '%$search%'
    GROUP BY b.title, b.pages;
```

Comment: Very important note from MySQL docs: The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. imho GROUP_CONCAT should only be used for reporting purposes and not in conjunction with php as it highlights a deficiency in your table design.

Comment: I was just reading about GROUP_CONCAT from the related questions, but I can't figure out exactly what is it doing. Could you elaborate what is going on here?

Comment: Never mind, just tried it in console and I think I understand. Also, how come you can use b.title instead of book? Does MySQL know to select correct table since it's the only 1 beginning with b?

Comment: @tutuDajuju `b` is an alias for the books table. I assigned the alias to the table in the `FROM books b` portion of the query. To make it clearer, you could add the optional `AS` keyword, `FROM books AS b`

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`authors`.`author`) AS `authors`
FROM `books` 
NATURAL JOIN `authors` 
WHERE `books`.`title` LIKE '%$search%'
GROUP BY `books`.`title`
```

Now your list of authors for each book will be comma separated under the field name `authors` for each book if you want them hyphen separated or another delimiter then use

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`authors`.`author` SEPARATOR ' - ')
```

**NOTE:** Grouping by title is not be the best way to group your search of books as many books can have the same title thus messing up the results.  It'd be best to group by ISBN number or some other unique identifier for each book.